# Path alias as arguments in views

Tags: views, 6, path-aliases

I would like to pass **path alias** as **arguments** to a views page. I tried the two methods [one](http://peterpetrik.com/blog/node-id-view-argument-from-seo-friendly-url-path) and [two](http://drupal.org/node/555752) but unfortunately this doesn't works.

What I want to do is, example.com/box/portfolio link should show the example.com/box/45, 45 is node of portfolio. My views page path is box/% and I used the arguments as Node Id.

[image]

Comment: is portfolio a  title of a node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the [Views Alias](http://drupal.org/project/view_alias) module, it does exactly what you need. Rather than making the change during the Views argument validation, this module will create a path alias to this View for every taxonomy term that can be an argument on the Views you select. Thus, example.com/box/45 can be accessed via example.com/box/portfolio, etc.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the problem is **box** is not taxonomy term

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to get the node ID (to pass as the "final" argument) from the URL given that the URL is box/% and the argument is a path alias (i assume this means that your node's has only one level (path-alias instead of path/alias)

You would need to use [drupal_lookup_path](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/drupal_lookup_path/6) instead of drupal_get_path_alias since the argument is already an alias.